# Add enhancements to a website (whether it be by C#, Chrome Extensions, etc.) -- Not sure what would work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, google-chrome, macros

There is a website that I visit often... let's call it www.example.com. And, I am able to interact with parts of this website. The interactions send XMLHttpRequest and get a response back through Javascript, jQuery I believe.

I'm not sure what technology will let me achieve what I want to do, and where to start. Basically, I want to add additional options/shortcuts that the site does not provide. I thought about maybe using a macro, but trying to use macro recording software is just a pain in the butt.

I inspected (using Google Chrome's Developer Tools) the XMLHttpRequest being sent back and forth and I noticed that it is simple JSON messages. I figured the best way to add enhancements to the site without waiting for the actual owners of the site to do so would be to simulate the website sending/recieving these XMLHttpRequest/Response and making additional adjustments to the DOM to provide extra shortcuts.

I don't want to interfere with the original site's functionality though... ie if I send a request and receive a response I want both the original script and my script to process the response. So, here is where I'm stuck... I'm not sure whether to go along the paths of creating a C# application or a Google Chrome extension (I use Google Chrome) or something else alltogether. Any pointers on what dev tools/languages will give me the ability to do what I want would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If you can expand your work to the browsers of other guys, then congratulations. You've made an XSS attack ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has [built in support for user scripts](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts). You can use these to modify the page as you see fit and also to make requests. Without more details regarding what exactly you want to do with these AJAX request it's hard to advise further.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted... to add additional functionality to specific sites. I'll look into how user scripts work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but as I understand it, you want to be able to make changes to a certain website.  If these changes can be done with js, i would recommend Greasemonkey for Firefox.  It basically lets you run a custom script when you are visiting a certain webpage/domain.  You can be as specific as you want about which pages use the script.  Once your script loads jQuery, it is really easy to add any functionality.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

You can find pre-written scripts for tons of sites here:

http://userscripts.org/

Comment: It was tagged google-chrome, and Chrome has use scripts built it (see Radu's post)

Comment: I wasn't aware that Chrome had user scripts built in, and thats pretty sweet.  But just because "Google-Chrome" is tagged, doesn't make Grease Monkey a bad answer...

Comment: You're right, I've used Grease Monkey it's pretty sweet too. They were one of the first to use idea of modifying websites with JS I think.